# How to read the first four bytes of a file in javascript and compare it with magic number of a particular format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

```
  <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

I need to upload a file with .wav format.I need to check the first 4 bytes of file and compare it with magic number of wav so that I can prevent duplicate file upload. How to do this?